# when saving to file, words after white space are ignored

Tags: c++

I've been working on saving to files and this was the result. The only problem is that anything after a space is ignored, (if you typed "john smith") it would print 
("the last person to use this file was: john") I am using codeblocks with the GNU GCC compiler. Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string name;
        ofstream saveData;
        ifstream Data;
        Data.open("Info.data", ios::binary);
        Data >> name;
        Data.close();
        cout << "The last person to use the file was " << name << endl;
        cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
        cin >> name;
       saveData.open("Info.data", ios::binary);
       saveData << name;
       cout << name << endl;
       system("PAUSE");
       saveData.close();
       return 0;
   }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strings objects of `ifstream` (including `cin`) use input from beginning till the first space, and space is SPACE, TAB, and NELINE.
So, you should use `getline` instead `cin >>`

Try this:

```
Data.open("Info.data");
getline(Data, name);
Data.close();
```

and

```
cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
//cin >> name;
getline(cin, name);
```

**UPDATE:**

By the way, in your code
after

```
   Data.open("Info.data", ios::binary);
```

you use

```
   Data >> name;
```

So, stream opened in binary mode is read by `>>` - it is not so good.

Comment: recommend a swap of istream for ifstream and whitespace for space.

Comment: what #include file is getline in?

Comment: getline(name); didn't work with #include <string>

Comment: am i using getline() wrong?

Comment: MSDN says it is in <string> - https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22string%2Fstd%3A%3Agetline%22);k(%22std%3A%3Agetline%22);k(getline);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true

Comment: @JakeWickham take care mixing >> and getline. >> stops at whitespace, but doesn't extract it from the stream. Stackoverflow is littered with questions from people confused by getline returning empty strings because an end of line was left in the stream after the user typed input and hit enter.

Comment: The usual advice is not to mix `getline()` and operator `>>` on the same stream AT ALL.

Comment: is getline() better than cin?

Comment: Better, no. It just performs a different job. A common trick is to read lines from the user with getline, and then write the line into a stringstream (`#include <sstream>`), and parse the stringstream with >> or more getlines, but getlines using a different delimiter than end of line. Read more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line